# Can py3_image run under non-root user?

Tags: bazel

I need to build a py3_image container run under non-root user (because of MustRunAsNonRoot Kubernetes policy). Is it possible under py3_image?

Answer (score 0):

[`container_image`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#container_image-1) has a `user` attribute which does this. The [`go_image` example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#go_image-custom-base) has an example of using it in a language image. For `py3_image`, it would look something like this:

```py
container_image(
    name = "user_image",
    # `py_image` defaults to "@py3_image_base//image". You'll need to
    # either use a base image with another user included or add the user
    # entry via a tarball (like the go example) or something.
    base = "@some_custom_base//image",
    user = "some_user",
)

py3_image(
    name = "example",
    # Override the base image.
    base = ":user_image",
    [all the other attrs the same before]
)
```